# How can I make an Ubuntu Samba Share **completely** writeable from Mavericks

Tags: macos, smb

I have a Samba share set up on an Ubuntu server 10.10.10.199
I am using user permissions on the server. I have shared the directory /var/www as [webroot]

```
[webroot]
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   path = /var/www
   browseable = yes
   create mask = 0755
   writable = yes
```

I can connect just fine and see all the files in the finder

```
cifs://10.10.10.199/webroot
```

From the finder I can create a new folder, and duplicate files that already exist, and they show up fine on the Ubuntu server. However, if I attempt to open a file from the share in Textedit it doesn't load and says the file is locked. I can open files in Sublime Text 3, but when I edit and attempt to save I get the following message:

> Overwite write-protected file /Volumes/webroot/test/test.html
>   When I click Overwrite I get the following error:
>   Unable to save /Volumes/webroot/test/test.html
>   Error: /Volumes/webroot/test/test.html is readonly

So why can I create folders and duplicate files from the Finder, but not edit and save existing files or create new ones from my text editor? And how can I fix it so that I can create and edit files with my text editor?

Answer (score 1):

Permission problems in Samba can be a bit tricky to diagnose.

What exactly is the command you are using to mount the share on the Mac?

At the command line could you go to the place where the share is mounted and do an `ls -l@` so that the permissions there can be checked. Do the same in one of the directories that is giving you problems.

Are you sharing an `ext3` volume and do you have Samba configured to use ACLs? If so then adding a line `nt acl support = yes` to your share definition will get them working and you get much nicer permission controls. They *should* be on by default but may not be.